# Extract python objects from a string

Tags: python, json, deserialization, text-parsing

I have files with data looking like

```
{u'session_id': u'6a208c8cfada4048b26ea7811cbac20f'}
```

That is, key value pairs and arrays of objects with key value pairs which are of the form `u'key' : u'value'`

More specifically, the files I see look like what one gets after calling `json.loads()`on a `JSON` file.

I want to some how get the data present in these files as python objects or at least valid `JSON` format `(some thing like reverse of json.loads())`  so that I can do something like `obj['session_id']` and get `"6a208c8cfada4048b26ea7811cbac20f".`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` from the `ast` module, which is better than using `eval` directly:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("{u'session_id': u'6a208c8cfada4048b26ea7811cbac20f'}")['session_id']
u'6a208c8cfada4048b26ea7811cbac20f'
>>> z = ast.literal_eval("{u'session_id': u'6a208c8cfada4048b26ea7811cbac20f'}")
>>> isinstance(z, dict)
True
```